# "Error watching file for changes: EMFILE" when init a react-native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-native, watchman

I want to init a react-native project, and steps:

First `react-native init testproject`
then  `react-native run-ios`

```
Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
{"code":"EMFILE","errno":"EMFILE","syscall":"Error watching file for changes:","filename":null}
Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1406:11)
```

Operation System Edition: OS X 10.12

Comment: Do you have npm installed globally?

Comment: @Xiaotao Are you running react-native on a mac? I noticed that this problem peculiar to users of Apple's mac os seirra. You may want to checkout https://www.fdp.io/blog/2016/09/21/macos-sierra-hang-on-react-native-init/ or https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/f6aa55b452ecda2f4c7a379e21647c88

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling watchman fixed this error for me.

```
brew uninstall watchman
brew install watchman
```

One more thing that worked for my teammate and may work for you is deleting `node_modules` directory completely and running

```
npm install
```

Note that `yarn install` did not work in this case.